# Dropping Column with all distinct values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I want to drop a column from the dataframe if all values are distinct and none repeat.

for example:

```
    ID  NAME    VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3
 0  1   Alpha   100     A1      ULV
 1  2   Alpha   100     A1      SMU
 2  3   Alpha   200     A2      UT
```

Column ID would get dropped since no values repeat and it would turn into this:

```
    NAME    VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3
0   Alpha   100     A1      ULV
1   Alpha   100     A1      SMU
2   Alpha   200     A2      UT
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Are you usin some Lists ? some Dictionaries ? some Tuples ..

Comment: maybe I can't see the difference but they both look identical to me?

Comment: I think in your output `VALUE3` should be dropped as well because all the values are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to check if each column has duplicated items:

```
import pandas

# Recreate example dataframe
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3],
    'NAME': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha'],
    'VALUE1': [100, 100, 200],
    'VALUE2': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2'],
    'VALUE3': ['ULV', 'SMU', 'UT'],
})

df = df[[col for col in df.columns if df[col].duplicated().any()]]
```

Output:

```
    NAME  VALUE1 VALUE2
0  Alpha     100     A1
1  Alpha     100     A1
2  Alpha     200     A2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max_ = max(df.nunique().to_list())


cols = []
for i, (key, val) in enumerate(df.nunique().to_dict().items()):
    if val != max_:
        cols.append(key)

df = df[[col for col in cols]]
```